# Cross Table Trigger MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have the following scenario:

I have a web app that reserves resources for the company where I work. The reservations are made, the resources' status is changed to reserved and everything. The problem is, once the time and date where that resource is reserved expires, I want to automatically change the status of the resource to `avaiable` again.

The easiest and probably only possible way to do this is via a `trigger`. Triggers are somehow easy to do, but I however, have never done a cross table trigger and don't even know if it is possible.

I'm confused as to which should the target table be, the time, event and definition should be.

Here's my db schema:

[image]

It's simple. I make a reservation based on the `schedule_intermediate` table's start and end time and then I verify if the resource is available to be reserved on that specific time and date(the one specified when the user is going to make the reservation).

If it is available, it is shown and later the reservation is made. The resource's status is changed to `reserved` and everything works so far, flawlessly.

But I need to change the status of this resource once the date and time expire:

Here's the modal on phpmyadmin about the trigger, I'm confused as to how should I elaborate it:

[image]

If anybody could give me an orientation on how to more or less do this, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

No a trigger will not help you here.  Triggers are fired when particular events occur (such as a row being updated).  But in your case, nothing is actually changing at the point the reserve timestamps goes into the past so there is nothing to fire the trigger.

This is a general problem in databases.  You will see it crop up a fair amount with data for real time events.

You have a couple of options:

1. As part of your application you can set up a maintenance job to run every minute and run the updates for everything that has dropped into the past.  The only real advantage to this is that you don't have to change your DB schema as a solution.
2. (In my opinion the better option) is to set the field which indicates "available" to being a "next available" timestamp.  That way "available" is anything where "next available" is null or in the past of `now()`.  This way requires modifications to your schema but will always be absolutely up to date and require no additional maintenance job.

**Final considderation**

Only you know the business for which this is being written.  However you should consider what happens if someone doesn't return the resource on time - what should the database do and how will it know?

It's common with this type of example to have a couple of fields against a reservation which  log the actual event (actual time the resource was checked out, actual time it was checked back in).

Notice that if you use this model, then you can create a trigger on update of the reservation that checks to see if the actual check in time is NOT NULL and updates the resource accordingly.